# Maximizing item value runs

Tags: diablo-ii

I've started gambling items in order to get better gear.  As expected, this is a very expensive endeavour, and I run out of gold in short order.  To this end, I am attempting to maximize my playing so I pick up the items that are worth the most.  I am aware that items that improve class skills, such as wands, orbs, and scepters, are worth a lot of gold when vendored.  I also pick up all magic items as well.  The problem is, many magic items only sell for 200-300 gold, while taking up a lot of space in my inventory.

I have attempted to search for a list that shows how affixes modify the base item value, but all my searches just bring up websites offering to sell me items for real cash.

So, my question is two-fold: does anyone have any tips on how to bring back only the most valuable items, magical or otherwise?  And does anyone have a list of how affixes modify the base price?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike Diablo 1, magic attributes do not significantly add to the value of the item, instead the base type is more relevant.

As you first pointed out; Wands, Sceptres, Staves and Orbs are worth gold based on the "character level" of the skills on them. For example, an orb with *+3 Firebolt* will be worth significantly less than an orb with **+3 Frozen Orb**. When you pick up caster weapons, throw away weapons without a **level 24 or level 30 skill level**.

**Body Armor** is also generally worth a lot more than weapons. In normal armor, look for full plate or ancient armor and any "Exceptional" or "Elite" armor will usually hit the gold cap. See all the armors [here](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/).

Finally, make sure your selling everything in **Hell difficulty**, as your Act (in normal) and Difficulty affect your maximum value. Act 1 normal is 5000g maximum, Hell difficulty (any act) is **35000g**.

It might also be worth making a "***Gold Find Barbarian***" character just for farming gold. This involves creating a barbarian with the "*Find Item*" skill who destroys everything in the "Travincal" (act 3) zone. The council members there drop significant gold, and drop even more gold with "Find Item" cast on their corpse.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be more clear about what you mean with "better gear". What aspect of the game are you interested in? PvE or PvP?

Second, you have to understand how gambling works. Throwing away gold at gambling could be the worst way to pass your time in Sanctuary.
According to the [Diablo Wiki](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Gambling) you have the following chances while gambling:

- Unique: 1/2000 (.05%)
- Set: 2/2000 (.1%)
- Rare: 200/2000 (10%)
- Magical: 1797/2000 (89%)

The only things you can affect while gambling are the ilvl of the item (that depends on your level, and affects the modifiers you can find on the item) and the cost of your gamble (that is only affected by some items, such as [Gheed's Fortune](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Unique_Charms#Gheed.27s_Fortune)).
This means that if you're looking for specific [modifiers](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Modifier), you need a higher level, but that would hurt your chances because you have a larger pool of modifiers to choose from. If instead you're after specific unique items, well, you can see your chances up there.

If you're looking for really powerful items you should consider starting collecting runes, especially if you have a ladder character, since some [Runewords](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Runewords) will give you the best items you can have (consider as an example an [Enigma](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Enigma) armor)

Another good option is to increase your [Magic find](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Magic_Find) chances, especially if you have a Barbarian with [Find item](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Find_Item).

If you still prefer gambling anyway, you should follow @Resorath 's advices, especially regarding selling items in Hell difficulty and having a Gold find Barbarian.